# Chi-square / Fisher test variable independence for an individual

Tags: self-study, chi-squared-test, independence, small-sample, fishers-exact-test

I have a data set of $\approx$100 individuals showing pulse rate before exercise, pulse rate after exercise, sex, smoker status, weight etc. for each individual.

I've been asked to select an individual at random to test whether **their** sex and smoker status are independent, with a hint that I might want to think about chi-square and Fisher tests.

If I were looking at the whole dataset, I could construct a $2\times2$ table with sex and smoker status and then run a Fisher test on that. However, I have no idea how to do it for a single individual. I can't find anything helpful in my textbooks or online either.
Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: Was it supposed to have been a trick question? How could sex & smoker status be independent or dependent w/i a single individual? What would that mean?

Comment: That's what I thought. Just in case I misinterpreted:

"Test the following hypotheses (using R) and report the results.
For an individual selected at random from the speciﬁed population
investigate:
(a) their sex and smoking habit are independent."

Comment: I guess I interpret that the same way you do. It isn't obvious to me that it is supposed to be a trick question (I don't know if it would be obvious in its larger context). Nonetheless, I have no idea what it could even mean for sex & smoker status to be independent or not w/i a single person.

Comment: I think I will just assume it means test the hypothesis that they would be independent for any random individual. Not sure what else it could be.

Comment: If this is a homework problem, please add the [tag:self-study] tag.

Comment: Although the language is bizarre, there is a reasonable interpretation. The sex and smoker status of a *randomly* selected individual are considered random variables. Presumably the dataset consists of randomly selected individuals from a larger population. This question therefore asks you to test for independence of sex and smoker status *in the population*, by means of the data available in this random sample, using a test appropriate for such random samples.

Comment: Thanks all, yeah that's how I decided to interpret it eventually. I think I have it now.